# how to handle data integrity problems with domdocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

Given a series of elements of the form

```
<td class="name">Product Name</td>
<td class="price">$10.00</td>
```

one can use domdocument() to parse a page containing, say, 100 name/price pairs into a group of 100 names and a separate group of 100 prices. However, if one of the prices is missing, you get a group of 100 names, and a group of 99 prices, and it's not clear which product is missing its price.

Using a regex to parse pairs of name/price data (making the price optional) makes it possible to identify which product lacks a price, as the result is 100 pairs, one of which has an empty price value. Is there some way to achieve this using domdocument(), so that it is not necessary to use regex to parse html?

EDIT: I tried dqhendricks' suggestion but I am getting a syntax error on the foreach loop with the following

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOT

<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="productname">a</td>
       <td class="price">1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="productname">b</td>
       <td class="price">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="productname">c</td>
       <td class="price">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="productname">d</td>
       <td class="price">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="productname">e</td>
       <td class="price">5</td>
    </tr>
</table>

EOT;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//table/tr/') as $node) {
    $name = $node->query('td[@class="productname"]');
    $price= $node->query('td[@class="price"]');
}

print_r($node);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

with this structure, wouldn't you be iterating through td elements and checking their class attributes? and if there are two name attributes in a row, you know that the first one was missing a price?

where is your parsing code? I imagine the problem is in there. are you just using xpath to get a list of products and a list of prices or what?

now if your html document is structured like this:

```
<tr>
   <td class="productname">x</td>
   <td class="price">x</td>
</tr>
```

you will want to iterate through the tr elements and check their contents, and you will easily know which products are missing a price.

EDIT:

```
 foreach ($xpath->query('//table/tr/') as $node) {
    $name = $node->query('td[@class="name"]');
    $price= $node->query('td[@class="price"]');
 }
```

Something like that anyways...

Comment: I'm parsing with `$product_names_nodeList = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[@class="name"]');` and `$prices_nodeList = $xpath->query('//table/tr/td[@class="price"]');` so I end up with two nodeLists. I then combine them into an array of name/price pairs, but this doesn't work if the total number of names/prices don't match up. (and even if it does, that could just mean one name was missing from one product, and a price was missing from another product). If there's some way to parse both types of data together (as I could with regex), that's definitely what I want.

Comment: I tried implementing this but I'm getting `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` for your foreach line. I'm wondering what might be making it invalid. I added the code I used for the test to the question.

Comment: @jela does $xpath->query('//table/tr/') return an array or other iteratable object? if not, what does it return? how have you been cycling through the query() results in the past?

Comment: @jela maybe $xpath->query('//table/tr/') is supposed to be $xpath->query('//table/tr')